# ASP.NET Core 3.1 - Get User Profile Image from Facebook Authentication

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have been trying on/off for the past couple of days to make my application work with Facebook as an identity provider. It more or less works by following the various tutorials available online, however, I am stuck when it comes to trying and get the user image profile as well. At some point I was able to see the `user_picture` within some context, but after many revisions and following the various fragmented tutorials online I am still stuck.

So can anyone please point me to a complete guide, or where I can find relevant resources, to also include the user profile picture from facebook?

Code:
Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
        services.AddControllers(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                             .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                             .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(faceBookOptions =>
        {
            faceBookOptions.AppId = "___";
            faceBookOptions.AppSecret = "____";
        });
        ...
 }
```

User.cs:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string>
{
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public User(string userName) : this()
    {
        this.UserName = userName;
    }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        string str = "";

        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> FacebookLoging(string returnUrl)
    {
        string str = "";

        return View();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that the magic happens within the `AccountController`, but I have been unable to make any of my breakpoints hit.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I managed. Below is the full set of steps I did (code has been adapted from [here](https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/10/aspnet-core-facebook-authentication_1.html)):

AccountController:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private readonly SignInManager<User> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<User> _userManager;

    public AccountController(SignInManager<User> signInManager, UserManager<User> userManager)
    {
        this._signInManager = signInManager;
        this._userManager = userManager;
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl)
    {
        ...
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        // Extract the claims and store them into the DB.
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (replaced existing `services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook` with the below):

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(faceBookOptions =>
            {
                faceBookOptions.AppId = "_____";
                faceBookOptions.AppSecret = "____";
                faceBookOptions.Fields.Add("picture");

                faceBookOptions.Events = new OAuthEvents
                {
                    OnCreatingTicket = (context) =>
                    {
                        ClaimsIdentity identity = (ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity;
                        string profileImg = context.User.GetProperty("picture").GetProperty("data").GetProperty("url").ToString();
                        identity.AddClaim(new Claim(JwtClaimTypes.Picture, profileImg));
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });
```

MOST IMPORTANT: I had made some modifications to the `_loginPartial.cshtml` script:

```
<li class="nav-item">
                <form id="external-account" action="~/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            @foreach (var provider in providers)
                            {
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account">@provider.DisplayName</button>
                            }
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </li>
```

In my case, the `action="~/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F"` was setup incorrectly, and it was set up as `action="~/Identity/Account/ExternalLogin?returnUrl=%2F"`. This was causing the redirection not to hit my controller.

I hope this helps other people

Comment: How did you get it to return to your callback method? Mine always just runs the OnCreateTicket and then goes to home

Comment: @KasperSølvstrøm: I honestly forgot what exactly was going on... What I do remember is that as far as authentication is concerned, there is a lot of stuff that is happening from behind the scenes. If I recall, you'd need to scaffold the application (or something like that) to get the full list of controllers and views and then you'd need to debug through them.